# How to detect rpm post scriptlet failure

Tags: rpm, yum, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

How to detect if the rpm package installation's post install section code failed ?

I've got bunch of rpm packages and want to find the packages that have failed in post install section.
Post install means, the bash script in post section of spec file.

Answer (score 1):

The rpm database doesn't store the exit status of the scripts. The only way to know if it failed is at install time, the `rpm` command exits with the status of the scripts it ran.

Comment: Actually I resolved it already, there is a way how to retrieve it from rpm package, even if you open rpm package with hex editor you will see the corresponding info.

Comment: Using a hex editor to look at the scripts? You can always just do: rpm -qp --scripts package.rpm

Comment: Actually `rpm` exists with exit code 0 even on post scriptlet errors.